# Layer Switcher using EXT JS

Tags: extjs, openlayers, geoserver

I am working in a application where the maps layers were published using GEOSERVER and display it on PANEL created by EXT JS using openlayes,
I Want to include layer switcher features inside a Treepanel  on EXT JS.

How can i bring all the WMS layer published under a particular Workspace inside a Treepanel to perform Layerswitching feature

Comment: It'd be useful to see some code. I'd imagine you can get everything you need from `map.layers[]`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are asking for, but there is a request type called getCapabilities that gets you the layers available on the geoServer. [This](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/wmts-capabilities.html) is an example of parsing the getCapabilities for a simple [WMTS](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/wmts-capabilities.js).